# Передача значений переменных php в сессию при событии js

Tags: php, javascript, события

При нажатии на кнопку нужно добвить в сессию массив(php)  - значения которого доступны в данном шаблоне.
мои мысли каковы - повесить события onclick , в функции добавить массив в сессию, а значения будут равняться вставкам echo php.
Я думаю это не верно.
Cкажите как правильно это делается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>[HTML](http://nowhere)</sub>

```
<button onclick='send()'>Отправить запрос</button>
```

<sub>[JS](http://nowhere)</sub>

```
array = '{"login": "user", "mail": "asshole@gmail.com"}';

function send() {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('array=' + array);
}
```

<sub>[PHP](http://nowhere)</sub>

```
if(isset($_POST['array'])) {
    $json = json_decode($_POST['array']);
    $_SESSION['login'] = $json->login;
    $_SESSION['mail'] = $json->mail;
}

echo !isset($_SESSION['login']) ? 'user empty, ' : $_SESSION['login'].'<br>';
echo !isset($_SESSION['mail']) ? ' mail empty <br>' : $_SESSION['mail'].'<br>';
```

---

<sub>user

asshole@gmail.com</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Ну отправляете данные с помощью XHR на php-скрипт и там записываете данные в сессию.

Comment: а можно поподробнее?

Comment: @ikerya, ваш ответ тянет только на комментарий.

Comment: @mydls1 а как подробнее? это основы. можно воспользоваться jQuery и чтобы не долбить себе мозги отправит ajax-ом данные, а в php эти данные получить из GET (или из POST) и записать их в сессию

Comment: @ikerya, можно и без jquery не долбить себе мозги и воспользоваться xhr. Не жирно ли библа в ~100кб для простого запроса?

Comment: @Doofy если Вам не нравится, можете Почтой России отправить данные php скрипту

Comment: @ikerya, пинг слишком велик будет